# Why are my node modules not being used in react-native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I don't understand why my node_modules are not being used can someone explain it to me ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's in use , just that in your `.gitignore` file you must have added like this :

```
# dependencies
/node_modules
```